# Can I make it faster? I iterates through 20k rows +/- for 4-5 minutes

Tags: vba, performance

I am trying to make a macro that assigns the name of maneuver (Ramping Up, Flat Cruise, Ramping Down) for specific behaviour of set of data. I decided to divide the large data set into subsets that consist 5 cells and the code is checking its behaviour (either is the value getting smaller or bigger).

.csv file consists more or less 20k rows and the code iterates through it for 5 minutes. Can I make it somewhat faster?

The outer for loop is dividing the set of data into subsets that consists 5 cells. Slow iterators manipulate those values.

Then it just assigns values depending the values in cells are decreasing or increasing

```
Sub maneuverSet(lu As Worksheet, nr As Long)
    lu.Activate

    Dim fast_ite As Long, slow_ite As Integer, numRows As Long
    
    Dim slow_1 As Long, slow_2 As Long, slow_3 As Long, slow_4 As Long, slow_5

    numRows = nr 'definition in main: numRows = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For fast_ite = 4 To numRows Step 5
        Dim ite_array As Variant
    
        slow_1 = fast_ite - 2
        slow_2 = fast_ite - 1
        slow_3 = fast_ite
        slow_4 = fast_ite + 1
        slow_5 = fast_ite + 2
    
        ite_array = Array(slow_1, slow_2, slow_3, slow_4, slow_5)
    
        ' Now it just checks if the cell consist the values that ramping up with each row or not.
    
        If Cells(slow_1, "A") < Cells(slow_2, "A") And Cells(slow_1, "A") < Cells(slow_2, "A") And Cells(slow_2, "A") < Cells(slow_3, "A") _
            And Cells(slow_3, "A") < Cells(slow_4, "A") And Cells(slow_4, "A") < Cells(slow_5, "A") Then
    
            For Each iterator In ite_array
                Cells(iterator, "AB") = "RampUp"
            Next
    
        ElseIf Cells(slow_1, "A") > Cells(slow_2, "A") And Cells(slow_1, "A") > Cells(slow_2, "A") And Cells(slow_2, "A") > Cells(slow_3, "A") _
            And Cells(slow_3, "A") > Cells(slow_4, "A") And Cells(slow_4, "A") > Cells(slow_5, "A") Then
    
            For Each iterator In ite_array
                Cells(iterator, "AB") = "RampDown"
            Next
    
        Else
    
            For Each iterator In ite_array
                Cells(iterator, "AB") = "Cruise"
            Next

        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried to check what actual `numRows = ` value you get? Mayb it is 1mil anyway?

Comment: It is not ; / msgbox shows 14101 as it should be

Comment: is it 14101  for the whole set of data or just for one "split" set for the loop?
it looks like, each loop uses the same `numRows` - if I am not mistaken

Comment: My intention was to take subset of 5 cells and assign each of cell to slow iterators.
This is done by 1st loop:
'For fast_ite = 4 To numRows Step 5'
Then the rest of the code should work just on those 5 cells and then repeat for another 5 cells (until it reaches 14101st)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read/write to/from cell is usually a very slow action so you will want to avoid that as much as possible.

Instead, store the values into an array then process the logic through the array.

Without changing too much of your logic, this is probably what an array approach looks like:

```
Sub maneuverSet(lu As Worksheet, nr As Long)
    
    lu.Activate
    
    Dim fast_ite As Long, numRows As Long
     
    numRows = nr 'definition in main: numRows = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For fast_ite = 4 To numRows Step 5
        'Assign the 5 values into an array for processing
        Dim dataArr As Variant
        dataArr = lu.Cells(fast_ite, "A").Offset(-2).Resize(5).Value
        
        Dim outcome As String 'used to store the outcome of this loop
        
        If dataArr(1, 1) < dataArr(2, 1) And _
            dataArr(2, 1) < dataArr(3, 1) And _
            dataArr(3, 1) < dataArr(4, 1) And _
            dataArr(4, 1) < dataArr(5, 1) Then
            
            outcome = "RampUp"
        ElseIf dataArr(1, 1) > dataArr(2, 1) And _
            dataArr(2, 1) > dataArr(3, 1) And _
            dataArr(3, 1) > dataArr(4, 1) And _
            dataArr(4, 1) > dataArr(5, 1) Then
            
            outcome = "RampDown"
        Else
            outcome = "Cruise"
        End If
        
        'Write the outcome into the 5 cells at once.
        lu.Cells(fast_ite, "AB").Offset(-2).Resize(5).Value = outcome
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Below should be even faster as it only read and write cells twice:

```
Sub maneuverSet(lu As Worksheet, nr As Long)
    lu.Activate
           
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Read the entire data into an array
    Dim dataArr As Variant
    dataArr = lu.Range("A2:A" & nr).Value
    
    'Create another array of the same size to store the outcome (to be written into column AB)
    Dim outputArr() As String
    ReDim outputArr(1 To UBound(dataArr, 1), 1 To 1) As String
    
    'Loop through the array as per your logic
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(dataArr, 1) Step 5
        Dim outcome As String
        
        If dataArr(i, 1) < dataArr(i + 1, 1) And _
            dataArr(i + 1, 1) < dataArr(i + 2, 1) And _
            dataArr(i + 2, 1) < dataArr(i + 3, 1) And _
            dataArr(i + 3, 1) < dataArr(i + 4, 1) Then
            
            outcome = "RampUp"
        ElseIf dataArr(i, 1) > dataArr(i + 1, 1) And _
            dataArr(i + 1, 1) > dataArr(i + 2, 1) And _
            dataArr(i + 2, 1) > dataArr(i + 3, 1) And _
            dataArr(i + 3, 1) > dataArr(i + 4, 1) Then
            
            outcome = "RampDown"
        Else
            outcome = "Cruise"
        End If
        
        Dim n As Long
        For n = i To i + 4
            outputArr(n, 1) = outcome
        Next n
    Next i
    
    'Write the entire outcome array into the worksheet
    lu.Range("AB2:AB" & nr).Value = outputArr
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I will test it right away when I come to the office! But I get my mistake here! Thanks for clarification!

Comment: I had a problem with declaration of iteration range with the first for.. loop.
I had to use dataArr size there for it to work for some reason.

Now it works fine. Thanks a lot :)